# How to prevent Yocto project BadValue error?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, kernel, yocto, qemu

After running `source oe-init-build-env` in poky (Git of yocto), I run bitbake and I compile, everything is running smoothly. After I do `source oe-init-build-env`, I move into the right folder path and I do `runqemu -qemux86-64 core-image-sato-qemux86-64.ext4` but I get this error

```
runqemu -qemux86-64 core-image-sato-qemux86-64.ext4
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=-qemux86-64 bitbake -e ...
runqemu - ERROR - /home/borix/git/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/-qemux86-64 not a directory valid DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE
runqemu - INFO - Continuing with the following parameters:
KERNEL: [/home/borix/git/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/bzImage--5.4.61+git0+7ed307f651_00809fdaf6-r0-qemux86-64-20200907175216.bin]
MACHINE: [qemux86-64]
FSTYPE: [ext4]
ROOTFS: [/home/borix/git/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-sato-qemux86-64.ext4]
CONFFILE: [/home/borix/git/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-sato-qemux86-64.qemuboot.conf]

runqemu - INFO - Using preconfigured tap device tap0
runqemu - INFO - If this is not intended, touch /tmp/qemu-tap-locks/tap0.skip to make runqemu skip tap0.
runqemu - INFO - Network configuration: ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0
runqemu - INFO - Running /home/borix/git/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-helper-native/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:02 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -drive file=/home/borix/git/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-sato-qemux86-64.ext4,if=virtio,format=raw -show-cursor -usb -device usb-tablet -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0   -cpu core2duo -m 512 -serial mon:vc -serial null -kernel /home/borix/git/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/bzImage--5.4.61+git0+7ed307f651_00809fdaf6-r0-qemux86-64-20200907175216.bin -append 'root=/dev/vda rw  mem=512M ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0 oprofile.timer=1 '

runqemu - ERROR - Failed to run qemu: X Error:  BadValue
  Request Major code 130 (MIT-SHM)
  Request Minor code 3 ()
  Value 0x400
  Error Serial #2385
  Current Serial #2386

runqemu - INFO - Cleaning up
```

BUT if I run `runqemu -qemux86-64 core-image-sato-qemux86-64.ext4 nographic` everything boots up smoothly. Why?

I would like the first command -> `runqemu -qemux86-64 core-image-sato-qemux86-64.ext4`
to work.

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/poky/topic/78854857#12308) maybe you should try the gtk+ backend for qemu-system-native by modifying your conf/local.conf